# Angular JS: How to use array as a model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

What I have is a list of `tasks` that is being generated using `ng-repeat`. Each of the task has a hidden form to update the task. Firstly, I am listing all the tasks in the form of `li`s and whenever some  `li` is clicked upon, I am trying to make the form visible and the task `li` to be hidden (using `ng-show` and `ng-hide`). In my view I have got the following

```
<span ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <li class="tasknum-{{$index}}  tasknum-{{$index}}-task" ng-click="toggleEditForm( $index )"  ng-hide="editTaskForm[{{$index}}]">
        ...
    </li>
    <!-- /.task -->

    <li class="task add-task-form" ng-show="editTaskForm[{{$index}}]">
        ...
    </li>
</span>
```

Since there would be multiple tasks, as you can notice, I have tried to use `editTaskForm[{{$index}}]` so that the model may work as an array. In my model, I have the following:

```
$scope.toggleEditForm = function ( index ) {
    $scope.editTaskForm[index] = !$scope.editTaskForm[index];
}
```

But due to some reason, I am getting `$scope.editTaskForm` to be `undefined`. For example, when I click first task `li`, it says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined!
```

Can any one please tell me, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to initialize the array in the first line of controller: ($scope.editTaskForm = [];)

Comment: Yes, to be on the safe side, always initialize the scope variables on the first lines of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing the array, as suggested by @Omar in his comment above, solved the problem!

```
$scope.editTaskForm = [];
```